# New created component is greyed out

Tags: web8, cme, sdl-cloud

I'm attempting to create a simple component in a DEV environment on an SDL Web Cloud (SDL Web Content Manager - Build 8.6.0, SDL Web Content Manager Explorer - Build 8.6.0.45274, Update Version - 0, SDL Web Experience Manager - Build 8.6.0.46292) within the content publication and it's greyed out once I save it. Google search came up empty.

What I've tried:

- Check the cd_client logs and found no errors.
- Check that my user/group has full permissions.
- Check the history of the component and version is 0.1 and with the comment "Creation".
- Inspect the component using Chrome inspector and found components have the class "ghost" applied to it.
- Check different browsers (Firefox and IE)
- Check the documentation for SDL Web Cloud and SDL Web 8.5 for any known issues with no luck.

Note: workflow is enabled on this environment and attempting to add the component to a bundle is also not possible.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update: Please see the correct answer by David Forster in the comments below.**

---

You may want to check whether there is Workflow set via the `Associated Component Process` on the Schema.

[image]

This may put the Component straight into Workflow (as a Version 0.1) without needing it to be added to a Bundle.

Comment: The Associated Component Process is set to (None) but the checkbox "Any changes made to a Component based on this Schema required approval by a Bundle Workflow Process" is selected with a legacy Workflow Process definition. I've checked for any active processes and nothing appears to have been started. I was under the impression that this won't apply on creation, just on modify. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's this. If you have the "Any changes made to a Component based on this Schema required approval by a Bundle Workflow Process" tick-box selected then the components need to go through workflow before they are fully checked in. Until then, they will exist in a "reserved" state (appearing greyed out), which is what you are seeing. There will be no active processes because you have not started one via a bundle or otherwise.

Comment: @DavidForster - That sounds familiar, now that you mention it. I think you should put that as a separate answer. If you don’t, then I’ll update my answer in a few days to include your idea (but I’d prefer you to get the credit!). :)

Answer (score 6):

If a component is greyed out when it's just created, this usually means it's created, but not yet checked in.

There are several causes for this

- you build the component using custom code, but you save it without checking in
- when you manually create the component in the CME gui, you save it, but you don't check in the component.
- some workflow process starts when creating the component, and this needs to be finished before the component is checked in
- there is some eventsystem code that intercepts the creation of the form and does something, but doesn't check in the result.

To test, could you open the component (or open the context menu of the component, and choose versioning -> check in ? Normally, then the version 1.0 of the component should be created, and it should no longer be greyed out.

Comment: Thanks, Harald, the check-in option is disabled when I checked. There is no event system code and there is no active workflow started as far as I can tell. When creating the component and prompted to add it to a bundle, I'm unable to select the new component.

Comment: can you clarify how you created the component ? Was this using XPM or via the regular CME Gui, or via code ?

Comment: Manually via regular CME GUI.

Comment: I also can't find a direct explanation. Since you have this on Web 8.5 Cloud, could you ask support to have a look at this ?